# Django query for listing all ForeignKey objects from related query

Tags: sql, django, database, django-queryset

I'm trying to do a simple query in which I retrieve all products from all payments from a single user object.

Here is the relevant model:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="payments")
    product= models.ForeignKey(Product)
...
```

Initially I have one user object called `user`. I can retrieve all payments with `all_payments = user.payments.all()`.

How can I extend the query to retrieve all the products associated with all_payments to get a list of all products the user has paid for? In the template I' like to loop through the list with {%for item in products%} without need to pass any payment lists into template.

And how should we change that query to remove all possible duplicate products from that QuerySet?

Now I'm getting the list by looping through the all_payments QuerySet but that feels like really bad way to do it...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
user.payments.all().prefetch_related('product')
```

To display in a template you can continue to use your `all_payments`

```
{% for payment in all_payments %}
    {% for p in payment.product %}
          {# do something with the product p #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: There is also [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not getting a query set of products, but payment objects. (Or single payment object in my test data). I must be missing something important here.

Comment: @Paapaa - Is that not what you wanted? Why do you need a queryset?

Comment: I got a list of Payment objects, but I'd like to have a list (query set?) of Product objects so that I can display all products a user has ever bought.

Comment: @Paapaa - But you don't need a queryset to do that, you can just iterate over the objects? This just makes it one db query instead of `n` queries which I thought was the aim

Comment: Sorry for being lost, still new to Django :) But how do I accomplish that? How do I now iterate all related Product objects with the query you suggested?

I'd like to just pass a list of products to template and use {%for product in products%.}

Comment: @Paapaa - Probably the same way your code is already doing it, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But I really need to pass a list of products to the template as the same template is used for listing other Product queries. So I guess it is not an option to pass all_payments to template and I'd rather pass a list of Products to the template.

Comment: @Paapaa - I'm not sure I fully understand, your question talks about extending the query to retrieve all products which this does, Its not clear what output you're expecting (to me at least)

Comment: I try to improve the question. Maybe I'm using the wrong terms here. I'd like to have a solution which allows me to use {%for product in products%} in the template. I don't want to iterate a payment list in the template. So I don't want to pass any payment data to template, just related products. And I'm already doing it but in a sub-optimal way (creating a list of games by looping a list of payments).